# Не работает сайт при mbstring.func_overload 2 - 1С Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Ставлю mbstring.func_overload = 2 и сайт ложится, а при 0 - нормально. Nginx + apache(FastCGI) + ssl + CentOS 7. Логи такие:

```
[Wed Mar 28 15:57:41.121796 2018] [fcgid:warn] [pid 17517] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 37.23.195.128:46454] mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server, referer: https://prokompressor.ru/bitrix/admin/site_checker.php?lang=ru
[Wed Mar 28 15:57:41.121900 2018] [core:error] [pid 17517] [client 37.23.195.128:46454] End of script output before headers: urlrewrite.php, referer: https://prokompressor.ru/bitrix/admin/site_checker.php?lang=ru
[Wed Mar 28 15:57:42.144942 2018] [fcgid:warn] [pid 17518] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 37.23.195.128:46456] mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server, referer: https://prokompressor.ru/bitrix/admin/phpinfo.php?test_var1=AAA&test_var2=BBB
[Wed Mar 28 15:57:42.145077 2018] [core:error] [pid 17518] [client 37.23.195.128:46456] End of script output before headers: phpinfo.php, referer: https://prokompressor.ru/bitrix/admin/phpinfo.php?test_var1=AAA&test_var2=BBB
[Wed Mar 28 15:57:43.305282 2018] [fcgid:warn] [pid 17520] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 37.23.195.128:46458] mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server, referer: https://prokompressor.ru/bitrix/admin/site_checker.php?lang=ru
[Wed Mar 28 15:57:43.305430 2018] [core:error] [pid 17520] [client 37.23.195.128:46458] End of script output before headers: ajax.php, referer: https://prokompressor.ru/bitrix/admin/site_checker.php?lang=ru
[Wed Mar 28 15:57:44.250496 2018] [fcgid:warn] [pid 17522] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 37.23.195.128:46460] mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server, referer: https://prokompressor.ru/bitrix/admin/site_checker.php?lang=ru
[Wed Mar 28 15:57:44.250665 2018] [core:error] [pid 17522] [client 37.23.195.128:46460] End of script output before headers: ajax.php, referer: https://prokompressor.ru/bitrix/admin/site_checker.php?lang=ru
```

Что все это значит? И что делать, куда смотреть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотреть в консоль разработчика в браузере (нажать F12). А имеено во вкладку Network и смотреть как грузится **ajax.php** и что он выводит (вкладка Response). Судя по всему он выводит сообщение об ошибке и выводится оно раньше вызова функции **header**. И как результат получается ошибка *End of script output before headers*

Ошибка веряотней возникает из-за того что включается переназначение обычных строковых функций на функции для строк в мультибайтовых кодировках **mb_** а модуль для поддержки этих функций надо ставить дополнительно. Подробнее: http://php.net/manual/ru/mbstring.setup.php

Comment: Да, выводит "500 Internal Server Error". Как найти взаимосвязь с mbstring.func_overload и этой ошибкой, какие тесты сделать или логи посмотреть?

Comment: Если отключить Opcache, то все нормально работает. А вместе не могут с mbstring.func_overload = 2. Хотя на других проектах нормально отрабатывают. Как это понимать?

Comment: Смотрите настройки сервера. Особенно в плане поддержки функций mb_* Дело в том  что если ставить в значение 2 - то ряд функций "заменяется" на функции mb_. Если не установлен модуль для их поддержки - то это может быть причиной ошибки. Ну и уточните версию PHP

Comment: php7.2 / Пока на memcache довольствуюсь. С поддержкой функций буду разбираться. А что за модуль, как его посмотреть?

Comment: Так с этого и надо было начинать. В 7.2 эту опцию признали устаревшей. Возможно поэтому попытка ее включить и вызывает ошибку.